# occurrences in multidimensional array

Tags: c

I have a 2d array which contains for example

```
dict[0][30] = "name1";
dict[1][30] = "name2";
dict[2][30] = "name3";
```

i'm using the following function to check for occurrences

```
char letters[] = {"abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"};

for(i = 0; i < size; i++)
    for (j = 0; j < 26; j++)
        if(tolower(dict[i]) == letters[j])
            count[j]++;
```

i have tested the code using 1d array and its working any example for 2d arrays

Thanks

Comment: And where is a question?

Comment: The code shown can only work in part.  If you have `char *dict[3][31];`, then the assignments work.  Your comparison loop should be failing with compiler warnings on `tolower(dict[i])`.  If it doesn't, you've either not posted what the compiler is seeing or you're ignoring compiler warnings, or you don't have the right headers or some combination of all the above.  Recommendation: post actual working code - not approximately working sort of similar to what you are compiling code.

Comment: #define N 3
#define M 26

char dict[N][M];

Comment: yes i have problem with tolower but my real problem is how to compare an 2d array with alphabet array

Comment: You seem to be dismissing the compiler warning on tolower as unimportant, but actually investigating on the warning will give you much insight on perceived and actual errors.

Answer (score 0):

```
dict[0][30] = "name1";
```

check if it is defining the variable.